# jQuery .each() index value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve been teaching my self JavaScript and jQuery for a few months, but I’m still getting confused with JavaScript objects and jQuery objects.

In the following example I assigned a jQuery object to the variable `$target`. The `$target` should consist of an array of two objects.

My question is why I have to wrap the `value` variable again into the jQuery object in `.each()` function ?

```
$('select.to_append').change(function(){
    var $target = $('select.to_append');
    var $form = $('#anotherForm');

    $.each($target, function(key, value){
        $form.append('<input name="' + $(value).attr('name') + '" type="hidden" value="' + $(value).val() + '"></input>');
    });
});
```

The sample code I use to append values from selects which are not parts of the form being submitted;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `$target` is a jQuery object, but when you iterate you will get a dom element reference in your iteration handler not a jQuery object. So if you want to access jQuery methods on that object you need to wrap the object again.

By the way to iterate over a jQuery object you can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('select.to_append').change(function () {
    var $target = $('select.to_append');
    var $form = $('#anotherForm');

    $target.each(function (index, el) {
        $form.append('<input name="' + $(el).attr('name') + '" type="hidden" value="' + $(el).val() + '"></input>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look up for difference between those two functions.